# how can I compare two test steps Json results!? in one test case with Groovy script?soapUI

Tags: json, groovy, automated-tests, soapui, assertion

I  do appreciate if anyone can help me with this error ,tried to compare Json responses in two test steps of one of my test cases.
the first step adds a task, and the second step gets a list of all tasks.
all I have in my Json file from first step is a number which is the TaskId of last added task. and i need to check in the second test step Json response whether that taskid exists or no? 
My Groovy assertion is :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def Response1 = context.expand( '${#ApiSmartsTaskPhysicalsPost - add an 
Unplanned task#Response}' );
def JSON1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText Response1;
log.info JSON1

def Response2 = context.expand( '${#ApiSmartsTaskPhysicalsGet -Check if 
values have been updated#Response}' );
def JSON2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText Response2;

log.info JSON2

assert JSON1 == JSON2
```

but I am getting this error :

> " java.lang.illegalargumentexception:Text must not be null ,error at
>   line:3 "

is there any chance to direct me to get solve this issue ? checked the end points they are the same and the URL is correct.

Answer (score 2):

solved I could fix it :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def Response1 = context.expand( '${ApiSmartsTaskPost - add an 
Unplanned task#Response}' );
def JSON1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(Response1);
log.info JSON1
def Response2 = context.expand( '${ApiSmartsTasksGet -check if task 
has been added#Response}'.toString() );
def JSON2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(Response2);
log.info JSON2
assert JSON2.taskid.contains(JSON1), "Task has not been created!"`
```